# Covert two tuples into Dict with one key: multiple values

Tags: python, django

I have two tuples, and I want to be able to convert them into dic with one key and multiple values. This will be written in python.

```
one_tup = [('A',1),('B',2),('C',3)]
two_tup = [('A',2),('B',4),('D',4)]
dic = {'A':(1,2),'B':(2,4),'C':(3),'D':(4)}
```

I was wondering if there's a faster and more efficient to do it without looping through each indexes and comparing it and then storing it. Because that's what I'm planning to do but I think it will take really long time given that I have about a couple thousand elements in each array.

Comment: You probably mean `'C': (3,)`, so that it is wrapped in a value?

Comment: Usually a linear algorithm is the fastest what you can do (complexity-wise), unless there is already some work done before.

Comment: You have to loop... or use some library with some magic function that will loop for you, but it will be the same probably

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `itertools` and `collections.defaultdict` like,

```
>>> import itertools
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> one_tup
[('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3)]
>>> two_tup
[('A', 2), ('B', 4), ('D', 4)]
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for key, val in itertools.chain.from_iterable([one_tup, two_tup]):
...   d[key].append(val)
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'A': [1, 2], 'B': [2, 4], 'C': [3], 'D': [4]})
>>> dict(d)
{'A': [1, 2], 'B': [2, 4], 'C': [3], 'D': [4]}
```

Note: You could use a `defaultdict` with `set`, instead of `list`, if you don't care about duplicate values like,

```
>>> d = defaultdict(set)
>>> for key, val in itertools.chain.from_iterable([one_tup, two_tup]):
...   d[key].add(val)
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {'A': {1, 2}, 'B': {2, 4}, 'C': {3}, 'D': {4}})
>>> dict(d)
{'A': {1, 2}, 'B': {2, 4}, 'C': {3}, 'D': {4}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually algorithms can not be faster than *O(n)*, unless some work (like sorting, indexing, etc.) has already been done in advance (or is a precondition). This makes sense, since if the algorithm is faster than *O(n)*, it means part of the input, is not necessary.

We can for example make use of a `defaultdict` here, and then map the items to tuples:

```
from collections import defaultdict

tmp = defaultdict(list)
for subl in (one_tup, two_tup):
    for k, v in subl:
        tmp[k].append(v)

result = {k: tuple(v) for k, v in tmp.items()}
```

For the given sample data, this gives us:

```
>>> result
{'A': (1, 2), 'B': (2, 4), 'C': (3,), 'D': (4,)}
```